# Passing JVM arguments to Tomcat when running as a service?

Tags: java, environment-variables, jvm-arguments, tomcat

I need to pass a couple of JVM arguments to the JVM which Tomcat is running in so that my application can pick them up.

I want to follow the process outlined [in this article to pick up environment](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0150.html) variables.

How would I go about doing this?

**UPDATE**
Sorry This is running under windows (7 on my Dev machine 2003 on client server)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to edit the Windows service. There are three ways to do this:

1. Start `Tomcat5w` with `//MS//`*ServiceName* to get an icon in the system tray which gives you a quick access to the configuration of the service.
2. Open the service manager in the "Control Panel". There is an entry for Tomcat.

In the editor, there is a tab where you can add additional JVM parameters.

The third way (which I prefer) is to write a script which edits the config for you. This way, you can save the config somewhere for backup. See the [docs how to do that](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/windows-service-howto.html#Updating_services) (Hint: use `tomcat5 //US//...`)

Answer (score 41):

**Windows:**

In your Tomcat /bin folder, you should have a tomcat5w.exe admin app (or in later versions tomcat6w.ex, tomcat8w.exe, etc). Go to the Java tab and add the args in the "Java Options:" box.

[image]

Note that when you add new args, you need to add them as NEW LINES in that box (above or below any others there), not as additional arguments IN FRONT or BACK of values on one of the existing lines.

**Linux / UNIX:**

In *nix, changes to the setenv.sh file should be picked up:

```
export JAVA_OPTS=-server -Xms2g -Xmx4g -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m $JAVA_OPTS
```

Don't touch catalina.sh or other files in bin

Comment: -1 The Windows service doesn't use the BAT files to start Tomcat.

Comment: Even when it's running as a windows service? It looks to me that windows executes the C:\apache-tomcat-5.5.28\bin\tomcat5.exe Although there is a command line argument //RS//<SERVICE_NAME>

Comment: @Aaron, sorry I realised the second I posted the answer.

Comment: I cannot find this Java tab. I have the service running on Windows 2008R2.

Comment: I tried using -noverify with the service java options - it doesn't work (the service doesn't start). Any idea?