# How to change java_opts for tomcat when we run it as a windows service manually?

Tags: java, tomcat, windows-services, console

I'm manually running tomcat 6 as a windows service on the console. I need to change java_opts before starting it. How do I do that? Also, Is there a way I can see the logs dynamically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing JVM arguments to Tomcat when running as a service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225682/passing-jvm-arguments-to-tomcat-when-running-as-a-service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To alter the `$JAVA_OPTS`, you will probably need to edit the batch file you use to start Tomcat.  I don't run Tomcat on Windows, but the `$JAVA_OPTS` appears in my `catalina.sh` inside the `bin/` directory on my Linux installation.

As far as viewing logs dynamically on Windows, there are a couple of options I'm aware of.

1. Download and install Cygwin, and then on the command-line, use `tail -f logfilename` like you would in Linux.
2. Get the BearTail program and use that to follow your log files.

Comment: This solution for JAVA_OPTS specifically does not work when Tomcat is ran as a **Windows Service**. See Kelly P Fitzgerald's answer, which actually works (tested on a Tomcat 8/Windows Server 2008).

Answer (score 44):

I know this is an old thread but needed to correct some assumptions.

Just an FYI, Catalina.bat is not utilized when running tomcat as a service. here is the method to change the JAVA_OPTS for tomcat running as a windows service.

1. Open Services and click on the Tomcat service. Make a note of the service name (most likely Tomcat6).
2. cd to the Tomcat bin directory
3. Run the command

   tomcat6w //ES//Tomcat6 (substitute your service name if different)
4. Click on the Java tab
5. Add the options (each on a new line) to the Java Options box and set the initial and max memory to 1536 and 2048

   -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
   -Djava.awt.headless=true
   -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
6. Click apply
7. Click on the general tab and restart the service

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what i was looking for. Only minor edit, step 3 was **.\tomcat7w.exe //ES//<service name>** in my case, without **.exe** it didn't work.

Comment: This should be the selected answer :)

Comment: this should be the selected answer +1  also, this link has a way of scripting it, rather than manual.  https://docs.lucee.org/guides/installing-lucee/windows/configuring-tomcat-as-a-windows-service.html

Answer (score 11):

To change the settings, create a file named setenv.bat for windows or setenv.sh for Linux with entry as below:

Windows:

```
set JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m"
```

Linux:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m"
```

Simply put this(setenv.bat/setenv.sh) file in %CATALINA_HOME%\bin\ folder. Your command file (catalina.bat/catalina.sh) already has a statement as below:

Windows:

```
if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\setenv.bat" call "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\setenv.bat"
```

Linux:

```
if [ -r "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh" ]; then
 . "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh"
```

elif [ -r "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh" ]; then
     . "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh"
  fi
This will take care the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your JAVA_OPTS environment variable either manually via the command line prior to starting Tomcat:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=youropts
```

or you can edit `catalina.bat` with the values you want.

Answer (score 0):

In windows, cut the quotes on the set command.  Quotes are taken literally.