# Setting JAVA_OPTS while installing Tomcat as windows service

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm-arguments, tomcat9

I am running multiple `Tomcat` instances on the same host and have installed them as windows services. Of course this is with distinct ports for each of the `Tomcat` instances. Now I am trying to extract the port numbers out of `server.xml` file and trying to pass them as JVM options, so that the `server.xml` file looks the same for all the `Tomcat` instances. Currently the Connector port in my `server.xml` file for each instance looks like:

**Instance 1**

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

**Instance 2**

```
<Connector port="8180" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

and I am trying to make it look like

```
<Connector port="${port.http}" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

As mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21261524/1036310), I can edit the options manually to add the parameter `-Dport.http=8080` or `-Dport.http=8180` and it works fine, but what I need is this JVM option to be set when `Tomcat` is installed as a windows service.

Below is the content of the `.bat` file I am running to install `Tomcat` instance1 as windows service (Its the same for instance2 except CATALINA_BASE, port and service name). As you see, I am also trying to set `JAVA_OPTS` before it is installed as a service, but I don't seem to have any luck with this. I have also tried it with double-quotes like `CALL SET "JAVA_OPTS=-Dport.http=8080"` and `CALL SET JAVA_OPTS="-Dport.http=8080"`

```
CALL SET JAVA_HOME=D:\Java
CALL SET CATALINA_BASE=D:\instance1
CALL SET JAVA_OPTS=-Dport.http=8080
CALL CD %CATALINA_HOME%\bin
service install instance1
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: use `setevn.bat` or something similar. Thats in Tomcats bin dir. It is included in servers startup routine

Comment: Hi @ antoniossss, Thanks for your response. I have tried using the `setenv.bat` also, but I don't think the options from there are referenced when Tomcat is running as a windows service

Comment: okay, but I have tried that too, but I can't use `${port.http}` in `server.xml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually I could resolve it by setting `JvmArgs` in the batch file that I use to install 'Tomcat' as windows service. The content of my `.bat` file looks like below:

```
CALL SET JAVA_HOME=D:\Java
CALL SET CATALINA_BASE=D:\instance1
CALL SET JAVA_OPTS=-Dport.http=8080
CALL SET JvmArgs=-Dport.http=8080;-Dport.shutdown=8005 // This line did the trick
CALL CD %CATALINA_HOME%\bin
service install instance1
```

I found this out when I was going through the code in `service.bat` file to check how the JVM options are set and found `%JvmArgs%` appended at the end as below:

```
--JvmOptions "-Dcatalina.home=%CATALINA_HOME%;-Dcatalina.base=%CATALINA_BASE%;-D%ENDORSED_PROP%=%CATALINA_HOME%\endorsed;-Djava.io.tmpdir=%CATALINA_BASE%\temp;-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager;-Djava.util.logging.config.file=%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\logging.properties;%JvmArgs%" ^
```

Hope this helps someone looking for a similar configuration :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set `-D` options as states in the title than you are interested in `--JvmOptions` https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html

eg

```
Install the service named 'Tomcat7'
C:\> tomcat7 //IS//Tomcat7 --DisplayName="Apache Tomcat 7" ^
     --Install="C:\Program Files\Tomcat\bin\tomcat7.exe" --Jvm=auto ^
     --StartMode=jvm --StopMode=jvm ^
     --JvmOptions -DwhateverHere
     --StartClass=org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap --StartParams=start ^
     --StopClass=org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap --StopParams=stop
```

Comment: Hi @antoniossss, Thanks for your answer. With this I can see its setting the parameter I wanted to set, but not the default ones (ex: -Dcatalina.home and -Dcatalina.base) which are set when I use `service install` command. Do you know why or a way to retain those? Otherwise I will have to manually set all of those.

Answer (score -1):

if you read carefully the details about jvmoptions in https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html you will see it says it does not work in exe mode.  I have confirmed this.  Even if the value appears in tomcat6w it does not usable in catalina.properties . In fact, even tomcat 8 & 9 state the same thing.  I would be happy if somebody could prove me wrong.  The quest continues....