# Getting error org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionInitializationException: Password not set for Password Based Encryptor

Tags: java, jasypt

I am using jasypt-1.9.0 for encryption.

Jdbc.properties

```
jdbc.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL
jdbc.username=testuser
jdbc.password=ENC(lKmVnTVL3zSJXrZpwFmhd6crSHLzYihH)
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
jpa.databasePlatform=toplink.hibernate.EssentialsHSQLPlatformWithNative
jpa.database=ORCL
```

```
C:\jasypt-1.9.0\bin>encrypt input=testuser password=testuser

----ENVIRONMENT-----------------
Runtime: Sun Microsystems Inc. Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 1.5.0_17-b04
----ARGUMENTS-------------------
input: testuser
password: testuser
----OUTPUT----------------------

lKmVnTVL3zSJXrZpwFmhd6crSHLzYihH
```

I got the reference from one of your site. I am using multiple context file. I have
configured

```
<bean
class="org.jasypt.spring.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfi
gurer">
<constructor-arg>
<bean class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor">
<property name="config">
<bean
class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.EnvironmentStringPBEConfig">
<property name="algorithm" value="PBEWithMD5AndDES" />
<property name="passwordEnvName" value="APP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD" />
</bean>
</property>
</bean>
</constructor-arg>
<property name="locations">
<list>
<value>classpath:/META-INF/props/db/jdbc.properties</
value>
</list>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
<property name="driverClassName"
value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" ></property>

<property name="url"
value="${jdbc.url}" ></property>
<property name="username"
value="${jdbc.username}" ></property>
<property name="password"
value="${jdbc.password}"></property>
<property name="initialSize" value="10"> </property>
<property name="maxActive"
value="30"> </property>
<property name="maxIdle"
value="10"> </property>
<property name="maxWait"
value="5000"> </
property>
<property name="removeAbandoned"
value="true"> </
property>
<property name="logAbandoned"
value="true"> </
property>

</bean>
```

When I login my application I am getting error::

> org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionInitializationException: Password not
>   set for Password Based Encryptor

Comment: Have you set APP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD as an environment variable?

Comment: I have check my configuration by using YOUR_PLAIN_TEXT_PASSWORD_HERE entry Its working fine.After using command prompt C:\jasypt-1.9.0\bin>set APP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD='lKmVnTVL3zSJXrZpwFmhd6crSHLzYihH' still same error is appear. I am strugling from last 2 days please help me out thanks

Answer (score 6):

It appears your "APP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD" property is not properly set as an environment variable. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html) link to check if it has been properly set as an environment variable. To check if there is a problem with the rest of your configuration, change `<property name="passwordEnvName" value="APP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD" />` to `<property name="password" value="YOUR_PLAIN_TEXT_PASSWORD_HERE" />` and replace YOUR_PLAIN_TEXT_PASSWORD_HERE with your plain text password to test if the rest of your configuration is working.

To set APP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD as an environment variable in Windows XP see this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519).

Alternatively, you can pass the password in as a vm argument when you run your program. If it is a standalone program, you will pass it like `java ClassWithMain -DAPP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD=your_password`. If it is a web application, you will have to pass the same arguments when starting your server. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225682/passing-jvm-arguments-to-tomcat-when-running-as-a-service) question on SO on how to do that for tomcat. Then in your spring configuration, replace `<property name="passwordEnvName" value="APP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD" />` with `<property name="passwordSysPropertyName" value="APP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD" />`.

Comment: I have check my configuration by using YOUR_PLAIN_TEXT_PASSWORD_HERE entry Its working fine.After using command prompt C:\jasypt-1.9.0\bin>set APP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD='lKmVnTVL3zSJXrZpwFmhd6crSHLzYihH' still same error is appear. I am strugling from last 2 days please help me out thanks

Comment: What operating system and version are you on?

Comment: hi jeshurun, I have set the environment variable in windows variable Name= APP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD Variable Value=lKmVnTVL3zSJXrZpwFmhd6crSHLzYihH change passwordEnvName to passwordSysPropertyName but still i am getting same error, what I will do i dont understand. Is the any entry is required my app servr (JBOSS)

Comment: If you set it as a windows environment variable then do NOT change passwordEnvName to passwordSysPropertyName. Only make that change if you are passing it as a startup parameter to your app server (using the -D<name>=<value> syntax.

Comment: set passwordEnvName after setting windows env variable showing error org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException

Comment: Try `-DAPP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD=testuser`

Answer (score -1):

Once you set the Environment variable. Please restart your eclipse.
    You may not face this isssue. If issue still persist than try to find your environment variables by below code..

```
Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
            for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
                System.out.format("%s=%s%n", envName,
                                  en`enter code here`v.get(envName));
            }
```