# How to add jvm options to tomcat on windows 7

Tags: java, tomcat

How can I add jvm options to Tomcat on Windows 7?. By the way I am using Tomcat 7. I added my jvm options to first line of `catalina.bat` file but it didn't work. I think I am doing something wrong. Is there any idea?

Comment: Try with file setenv.bat (add this file)

Comment: @MariuszS There is no file named setenv.bat?

Comment: As MariuszS said, you should add the file yourself and add the JVM options in there. Catalina.bat will check if this file exists and execute it.

Comment: @Pieter I created a file named setenv.bat in bin directory and added set JAVA_OPTS=-Dproject.home=C:\Users\myproject  but didn't worked.

Comment: Do you get a specific error? Or could you describe in more detail what is not working?

Comment: @Pieter It couldn't find the path for project.home

Comment: @hellzone How are you starting your server? Can you post the complete command?

Comment: Running as a service? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225682/passing-jvm-arguments-to-tomcat-when-running-as-a-service/6225719#6225719

Answer (score 4):

Create the file `bin/setenv.bat`. If you are using `bin/startup.bat` or `bin/catalina.bat` to start Tomcat, then the `setenv` script will be run before performing most other operations. You can set whatever JVM options you want by setting the `CATALINA_OPTS` environment variable.

If you are using Tomcat's service launcher from Microsoft Windows' services panel to launch Tomcat then you cannot use this technique. Instead, you'll need to run `tomcat7.exe` with the appropriate [options you can find here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html#Updating_services).

Note that you can also set `JAVA_OPTS` but `JAVA_OPTS` will be used for all JVM processes, including the one launched to request a shutdown of Tomcat. For example, if you want to enable RMI services for Tomcat and you set them in `JAVA_HOME`, then Tomcat will start up properly but when attempting to shutdown, the shutdown process may fail due to port conflicts. Similarly, if you need a 20GiB heap for Tomcat and you set `-Xms` and `-Xmx` in `JAVA_OPTS`, you'll end up creating a 20GiB heap for the process that *stops* Tomcat. So, use `CATALINA_OPTS` unless you have a very good reason to use `JAVA_OPTS`.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have my two cents,

Use **CATALINA_OPTS** or **JAVA_OPTS**. You can set the `jvm options` in either one of these variables in `catalina.bat` file according to your requirement. Read the comments in catalina.bat file about these variables. You will understand

**EDIT** after your comment

1. Set the environment variable - **project.home** in windows
   environment using this [link](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm). Now, your env variable is set
2. Set the JAVA_OPTS in setenv.bat (you need to create this file)

   set JAVA_OPTS="-Dproject.home"

or

```
  set JAVA_OPTS="%JAVA_OPTS% -Dproject.home"
```

for safety purpose. This will prepend the existing `JAVA_OPTS` with the new value.Start the server. Always, use UPPERCASE LETTERS, NUMBERS AND UNDERSCORE for environment variables. This is for portability reasons.

Comment: I read all comments in catalina.bat but I didn't understand anything.

Comment: can you post the options you want to add?

Comment: -Dproject.home=C:\Users\myproject

Comment: the output of echo %project.home% is "%project.home%"

Comment: then, environment variable is not set properly. set it correctly

Comment: echo %java_home% works good it points jdk location but when i set variable name=a and value=b then I write echo %a% and It writes "%a%". I don't understand.

Comment: can you execute set > env.txt in command prompt to list all environment variables. This command will write all the environment variables to env.txt in the same directory

Comment: in env.txt file I can see "Dproject.home=C:\Users\myproject"

Comment: Change the environment variable 'Dproject.home' to 'project.home'. Remove the 'D' in the env variable name. but, don't forget that you should put -D while setting in the JAVA_OPTS to denote it is a user defined system variable

Comment: You should not modify `catalina.bat` (or `catalina.sh`). Instead, create a `bin/setenv.bat` (or `bin/setenv.sh`) file and set whatever options you need there.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I have mentioned in the second point - Set the JAVA_OPTS in setenv.bat (you need to create this file) or catalina.bat file.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz removed catalina.bat file from answer

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using `context.xml` for tomcat environment variables:

File `conf\context.xml` should looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context>

     ...

     <Environment name="project.home" value="C:\Users\myproject" type="java.lang.String"/>

</Context>
```

After this environment variable `project.home` is simply accessible inside your tomcat app.

Comment: This won't work, because JVM options can't be set after the JVM launches.

Comment: `project.home` looks like option for web application inside tomcat for me, but you are right, this is not working for JVM.