# How to add JVM arguments to Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat7, jvm-arguments

I am using Tomcat 7 and I want to add the following JVM argument:

> -Xbootclasspath/p:PrintServiceFixer.jar

I added the aforementioned JVM argument in the tomcat windows application but it didn't work. I received the following error message:

> WARNING: Bootstrap: command "-Xbootclasspath/p:/Path to Jar
>   file/PrintServiceFixer.jar" does not exist.

Why isn't this working?

**SOLUTION:**
I added Startup VM parameter "-Xbootclasspath/p:C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\PrintServiceFixer.jar" to Tomcat 7 from tomcats windows application and it works now.

[image]

Comment: Care to share how you added the JVM argument for Tomcat...

Comment: Is that `p:` drive available to your Tomcat app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add jvm options to tomcat on windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658205/how-to-add-jvm-options-to-tomcat-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You provided simple value

```
-Xbootclasspath/p:PrintServiceFixer.jar
```

Are you sure that PrintServiceFixer.jar is in the home directory of Tomcat? Where is this home directory?

To be sure and avoid misunderstanding better provide full pathname to your jar file. Something like

```
-Xbootclasspath/p:/etc/allJars/PrintServiceFixer.jar
```

This boot class path may contain multiple jars and directories where classes reside. Just use full path name to the each jar or location.