# Tomcat runs as a service, how to tweak memory settings without UI

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, jvm

I would like to modify JVM heap min and max values as well as permGenSpace in a Tomcat that runs as a service on Windows machine. Is this possible using setenv.bat or the only way is to pass these values from UI?

Comment: Yes you can set JVM options using setenv.bat as specified in docs. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E40518_01/integrator.311/integrator_install/src/cli_ldi_server_config.html

Comment: Oracle doc says that setenv.bat is used by catalina.sh/catalina.bat. These files are not available when Tomcat runs as a service, instead there are only Tomcatx-service.exe and Tomcatx-servicew.exe as well as 2 other jars under bin directory.

Comment: See if this answer helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225682/passing-jvm-arguments-to-tomcat-when-running-as-a-service