# how to set TomEE to recognise when jvm arguments passed to it change

Tags: java, arguments, apache-tomee, jvm-arguments

I need to change my properties based on environment passed as argument to tomEE 6 server.

I have the following code:

```
String envProperties = System.getProperty("envProperties");
System.out.println("environment properties: "+envProperties);
```

This gets the property value that is set the first time. 
When I change the property to something different than the previous one, it doesnt detect the change. 
how do i get it to pick up any change being passed.

The way I am passing properties right now is by going into server run time configuration in eclipse and passing it

```
-DenvProperties="dev"
```

i tried following the post [Passing JVM arguments to Tomcat when running as a service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225682/passing-jvm-arguments-to-tomcat-when-running-as-a-service), but i cant find anything matching Tomcat5w or ending with 5w. Please help

Answer (score 0):

TomEE does not look into the Eclipse run time configuration. If you need to pass variable values to the running Java EE application, you have two options:

- pull properties periodically from a resource (file, network...)
- push properties from the outside using HTTP requests or other supported protocols (TCP, JMS, JMX, ...)

Comment: I didnt understand when you say "pull properties periodically from a resource (file, network...)"  I thought maybe I could just change the value in some file and TomEE will pick it up when i referred this link http://tomee.apache.org/system-properties-files.html. I am not sure where and how to set it though.