# How to enable java flight recorder for tomcat installed on my windows machine?

Tags: java-8

I have a web app running inside my tomcat on my windows machine. I am trying to monitor it with Java Mission Control. I am getting an error message to unlock commercial features to access java flight recorder.. Please guide me where and how it needs to be enabled.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: you have to start your app with some parameters: https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/jmc-5-4/jfr-runtime-guide/run.htm#JFRUH176

Comment: Thanks Eugene for the prompt reply.. But this is what I am struggling with.. How to start my app with those parameters.. This is what I was trying with but all in vain..C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\bin>java -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+F
lightRecorder -XX:StartFlightRecording=duration=60s,filename=myrecording.jrf startup.bat
Could not start recording, not able to write to file "myrecording.jrf"
Error: Could not find or load main class startup.bat

Comment: that is not how you do it... I bet the `startup.bat` is the file that *starts* tomcat and inside it there is the `java` command

Comment: Sorry Eugene, but I will bug you more on this.... I am trying to do flight recording for JMeter. As soon as I start flight recording from JMC I see an error message to Unlock commerical features in JVM first to proceed.. Where should I go to unlock the commercial features and how should I launch JMeter. As of now to launch Jmeter I go to the bin directory and open jmeter.bat file.

Comment: this is *not* about JMeter or Tomcat - I hoped you understood it by now. these are java processes that start with `java ... ` and some commands, what you have to do is add a few commands for the `JFR`

Comment: Finally was able to do it. thanks a lot..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing JVM arguments to Tomcat when running as a service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225682/passing-jvm-arguments-to-tomcat-when-running-as-a-service)

Answer (score 0):

You might try setting the `CATALINA_OPTS` environment variable, e.g.:

```
set CATALINA_OPTS=-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=7091 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7091 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Then start Tomcat as usual.